# Why wont my code run? Java program to add numbers

Tags: java, methods, logic, addition

Can you help me find my error?
I'm trying to use these two methods here but my output is not working.

```
class Nine {
    public static void Nine(String[] args) {
        int x,y,z;
        y = 3;
        x = 7;
        z = addEm(a, b);
        System.out.println("answer= " +x);
    }
    public static addEm (double a, double b){
        int c;
        c = a+b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your main method?

Comment: return type for addEm method? You may want to output z instead of x?

Comment: SO is not a debugging service, even for small programs. Please state a clear question that can be answered and could be useful for future visitors

Comment: You program won't run because it won't compile!

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are a lot of error in your code:

```
        z=addEm(a, b);
```

here a and b are meaningless, you should use `z=addEm(y,x);` (if your intent is to sum three with seven)

```
        System.out.println("answer= " +x);
```

I guess that you want to show the the results of the sum, therefore you should print z (and not x), so you should substitute with `System.out.println("answer= " +z);`

```
    public static addEm (double a, double b) {
```

Here you missed the return type, and you need to consider also the type of parameters a and b. Since y,x and z are int, it is better if also a and b are int, and therefore specify also the return type as int:
        public static int addEm (int a, int b) {

Or you can declare everything (y,x,z,a,b and return type) as a double: the important here is that they should be all of the same type. Moreover you miss also the return statement of the function addEm, that summarizing becomes:

```
public static int addEm (int a, int b)
{
    int c;
    c=a+b;
    return c;
}
```

And finally also the function

```
public static void Nine(String[] args)
```

it is not right named for an entry point: its names should be main.

So in conclusion, if you apply all the fix (by modifying as less as possible your original code) a code that compile, run and works following some 'logic' is:

```
class Nine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x, y, z;
        y = 3;
        x = 7;
        z = addEm(y, x);
        System.out.println("answer= " + z);
    }

    public static int addEm(int a, int b) {
        int c;
        c = a + b;
        return (c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, this is a very basic java lesson:

every prog need an entry point, which is in java:

```
public static void main(String args[]){}
```

And then your code will execute.

Comment: Actually that's not true. There's a few other problems with the code that'll make the compiler have a fit.

Answer (score -1):

You're passing arguments a and b to addEm, but those variables aren't initialized. I'm expecting you wanted to pass x and y instead.

```
class Nine 
{
  public static void Nine(String[] args) 
  {
    int x,y,z;
    y=3;
    x=7;
    z=addEm(x, y);
    System.out.println("answer= " +x);
  }
  public static addEm (double a, double b)
  {
    int c;
    c=a+b;
  }
}
```

Comment: this will not compile because the params for `addEm` are double and you are trying to pass int to it. also the method does not have return type.

Comment: This is true. There were many issues with the original, my answer fixed one of the many issues.
Is it bad to fix part of a problem?

Comment: No offence but that didn't solve the problem. did it?

Answer (score -1):

Your code will not work because your `addEm` method does not have any return type. In addition, the method you wrote takes Double params but while using you are trying to pass int to it. You also do not have any main method. I am assuming you misspelled or misunderstood the main method so below is the code which should work

```
class Nine 
{
  public static void Main(String[] args) 
  {
    int x,y,z;
    y=3;
    x=7;
    z=addEm(x, y);
    System.out.println("answer= "  + x);
  }
  public static int addEm (int a, int b)
  {
    int c;
    c=a+b;
    return c;
  }
}
```